# Socket.IO double fire

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using Socket.IO to send data from my client to my node.js server. When I receive the data from the client I am simply logging it. However the data logs two times where I only expect it to log once?

Here is the client side code

```
btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    socket.emit("comparison", "hello");
 });
```

Here is the server-side code

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
   socket.on("comparison", (data) => {
    console.log(data);  
    })
 })
```

It logs 
'hello
 hello'

Any idea as to what this is?

**UPDATE**

I still haven't fixed the problem although I've noticed when I take the socket code outside of the express route code there is only one log

Comment: what is the selector used for btn?

Comment: @karthick `const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");`

Comment: you don't have to put io.on("connection") inside app.get("/").

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'll upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put io.on('connection') inside app.get('/'). What you are doing here is registering an event listener on every get request. The reason why you are seeing two statements is directly related to the number of requests handled inside your app.get().

Take a look at the example provided in the socket.io site
https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express

I have added a simillar boilerplate of the code here,

```
const express        = require('express');
const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
const app            = express();
const port           = 8000;

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

server.listen(port,() => {
    console.log("server listening on"+port);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  //do something
});


io.on('connection',function(socket){

  socket.on('comparison', function () {

  });

});
```